# subtitles in tcolorbox like in mdframed

Tags: mdframed, tcolorbox

Until now, I have used [mdframed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) to produced nice framed boxes. I recently discovered [tcolorbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox), and found that it has several advantages over mdframed. In my actual and future work I would prefer tcolorbox. Nevertheless, one nice thing in mdframed is the `\mdfsubtitle`. You can divide a framed box into several "sections" with nice formatted titles, as seen in the picture (copied from the mdframed documentation):

[image: example of an framed box with one subtitle; copied from the documentation]

**My Question:** is there a (more or less) simple way of having such subtitles with tcolorbox?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You can have exactly one upper and one lower box with the `tcolorbox` command. However, you can nest boxes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there are no direct options like in `mdframed` but you can easily build your subtitle box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
   enhanced,
   bottom=1pt,
   top=1pt,
   arc=0pt,
   boxrule=.4pt,
   before=\vskip6pt,
   colback=yellow!70!white,
   oversize
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title=Theorem,colbacktitle=yellow!70!white,colback=blue!20!white,coltitle=black]
     Some text ...
  \begin{mybox}
     test
  \end{mybox}
     some text
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to create a custom tcolorbox (`mybox` in the mwe) that you'll use as a subtitle box. Every time you want a subtitle just nest a `mybox` into your main box and you're set. The inner boxes use the `oversize` key which removes the margin of the outer box giving the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

`tcolorbox` now has a `\tcbsubtitle` option:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
   enhanced,
   bottom=1pt,
   top=1pt,
   arc=0pt,
   boxrule=.4pt,
   before=\vskip6pt,
   colback=yellow!70!white,
   oversize
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title=Theorem,colbacktitle=yellow!70!white,colback=blue!20!white,coltitle=black]
     Some text ...
     \tcbsubtitle{test}
     some text
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I discovered this feature recently. It's nice to have subtitles directly implemented into the package.