# Subtitle at top of tcblower has spurious space above

Tags: tcolorbox

I am using `\tcbsubtitle` to place a title at the top of a `tcblower` and want a different background color on the two portions. This results in an unwated space above the subtitle:

[image]

How do I eliminate this undesired space?

### References:

- [Breaking tcolorbox between upper and lower part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357908/4301)
- [subtitles in tcolorbox like in mdframed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173051/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\LoremIpsum}{%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.%
}

\tcbset{My Box Style/.style={
    colback=green!20,
    bicolor,  
    colbacklower=yellow!60,
    %segmentation at break=false,% No effect
    %middle=0pt,% <-- This isn't it!
}}

\newtcolorbox{example}{My Box Style}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}
    \LoremIpsum
    \tcblower
    \tcbsubtitle{Subtitle}
    \LoremIpsum
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that this is the similar post that I remembered seeing earlier: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414537/tcolorbox-background-color-of-subtitle

Comment: @Andrew: Good find. I wasn't able to locate it. Thanks. Am voting to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Second attempt**
It seems to be controlled by `middle` and `boxsep`. If we set them both to be zero the we get:

[image]

It's not immediately clear to me that this is better than the previous manual adjustment. First, there is a faint hint of a yellow line above the subtitle line. Secondly, as explained on page 11 of the manual, `boxsep` is added all over the place, which is why this kills off the space at the bottom of the green box and the height of the subtitle.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\LoremIpsum}{%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.%
}

\tcbset{My Box Style/.style={
    colback=green!20,
    bicolor,
    colbacklower=yellow!60,
    middle=0mm,
    boxsep=0mm,
    subtitle style={}
    %segmentation at break=false,% No effect
    %middle=0pt,% <-- This isn't it!
}}

\newtcolorbox{example}{My Box Style}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}
    \LoremIpsum
    \tcblower
    \tcbsubtitle{Subtitle}
    \LoremIpsum
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

**First attempt**

I have a feeling that I have seen this before but I cannot find it.

The `\tcbsubtitle` command actually inserts a new `tcolorbox` that contains the subtitle, so I suspect that this gap is caused by some skip above this box. There should be some way to remove this but I have not found it.

The following hack adds a manual `\vspace` command above the subtitle, but there should be a better solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\LoremIpsum}{%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.%
}

\tcbset{My Box Style/.style={
    colback=green!20,
    bicolor,
    colbacklower=yellow!60,
    subtitle style={before={\vspace*{-3.1mm}}}
    %segmentation at break=false,% No effect
    %middle=0pt,% <-- This isn't it!
}}

\newtcolorbox{example}{My Box Style}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}
    \LoremIpsum
    \tcblower
    \tcbsubtitle{Subtitle}
    \LoremIpsum
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

You could also use `\tcbsubtitle[before={\vspace*{-3.1mm}}]{Subtitle}`, but using the style command seems more elegant.

Comment: Seems to work, but had to change the amount for my particular use case. There must be  an exact amount or some setting for this, but this is a great workaround until then. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterGrill Even into a normal `tcolorbox` a `tcbsubtitle` leaves some space on top of it. I think it's `\top+\boxsep` plus some other value that I cannot relate with geometry settings.